# Android Calendar - event snooze poor functionality - any settings?

Tags: calendar, reminders

I have been struggling with Android Calendar event reminders for quite some time, leading to missing events and reminders.
The snooze function is very poor. If you miss the event (don't press snooze or dismiss), it doesn't remind again, just stays in the "notifications" but no new sound etc. at any point. Even if you snooze it, often the event does not appear again, or it appears only once.
The problem is, when the event appears, it goes away quickly, if you don't notice it, there is no other reminder coming automatically.

I have found 0 settings (Samsung S8 phone) to change the behaviour. I recall the functionality was much better on Windows Phones, and hell, even in old Nokia phones with Symbian.

I use the calendar a lot, but to be honest it makes me miss many reminders, noticing those late - not very useful.

Is there really any settings for these?
Are those any better in newer smartphone models or same **it in different package?

Comment: As a first step I would disable battery-optimization for the calendar app.